# Local history in Atom Editor

Tags: eclipse, git, atom-editor

I've found [a package](https://atom.io/packages/local-history) in atom packages but I haven't downloaded it yet. 
Is there any way to check local history as it is in Eclipse?

I use git. But when I diff the file, I see all changes. However, I want to get chronological changes, how file is envolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [git-history](https://atom.io/packages/git-history) package:

> Git History Package for Atom
>
> View previous versions of any file known to git. By default, the plugin will now show a diff with the selected version. This can be disabled in the settings.
>
> `apm install git-history`
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another package for viewing a file's Git history.

> [Git Time Machine](https://atom.io/packages/git-time-machine) - *a package for Atom that allows you to travel back in time! It shows visual plot of commits to the current file over time and you can click on it on the timeplot or hover over the plot and see all of the commits for a time range.*
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [github-camo.com](https://i.github-camo.com/62085307dccead1c2f5efdf4d7a40f9cdb777b93/68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f6c6974746c656265652f6769742d74696d652d6d616368696e652f6d61737465722f7265736f75726365732f74696d656d616368696e652e676966))</sub>

If you'd like to see this package in action, I made a short YouTube video demonstrating the package. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFAzqvYoHJs&t=7m58s